# Add positive button to Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a very simple custom dialog and I wan't to add a positive button without having to modify the XML file, just like you would do it with an AlertDialog but I don't know if it's possible. This is the code:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MyActivity.this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Settings");
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Then why don't you build an `AlertDialog` and set your custom layout on that (or actually, the `Builder`)? See [`.setView(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView%28android.view.View%29).

Comment: I will if it's the only option but mine seems like an easier way to show a dialog.

Comment: I wonder what 'seems easier' compared to using `AlertDialog.Builder`? Also, above approach does not comply with the developer guidelines, meaning that I would recommend changing it, no matter what it seems. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use the builder.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View dialog_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.dialog_root_layout));
AlertDialog.Builder db = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
db.setView(dialog_layout);
db.setTitle("settings");
db.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    }
});
AlertDialog dialog = db.show();
```

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance but where are you assigning the layout in `dialog_layout` to the dialog?

Comment: It was missed, but you would just add it like `db.setView(dialog_layout)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the AlertDialog.Builder class:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

Create a new instance of it with `AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)`.  Then use methods such as `setTitle()` and `setView()` to customize it.  This class also has methods for setting the buttons.  `setPositiveButton(String, DialogInterface.OnClickListener)` to set up your buttons.  Finally, use `AlertDialog myAlertDialog = myAlertDialogBuilder.create()` to get your instance of AlertDialog, which you can then further customize with methods such as `setCancelable()`.

Edit: Also, from the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

"The Dialog class is the base class for creating dialogs. However, you typically should not instantiate a Dialog directly. Instead, you should use one of the... subclasses"

If you really don't want to use an AlertDialog, it'll probably be best to extend the Dialog class yourself, rather than using it as-is.

Answer (score 1):

You also can use this function

```
public void showMessage(String title,String message)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
    builder.show();
}
```